# Check Route Prefix in Blade If Loop

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route defined like such:

```
Route::get('aanmelden/{companySlug}/{packageSlug}', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'UsersController@create'])
```

I want to display some extra plug-in on this specific page, so in the header I want an if loop that checks for the prefix 'register' to display the code.. No luck yet. I tried this:

```
@if(Request::is('register'))

@if(Request::path() == 'aanmelden')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check route name, do something like this:

```
@if (Route::currentRouteName() === 'register')
```

If you want to check if route name starts with `register` (so it's like prefix), use [`starts_with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-starts-with) helper:

```
@if (starts_with(Route::currentRouteName(), 'register'))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank :-)

Answer (score 2):

You might also go like:

```php
@if (Route::is('register*'))
```

which is shorter.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-is